# nagios authentication bypass if from ip address also says logged in as?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, nagios

Im trying to bypass authentication via

```
AuthUserFile /etc/nagios3/htpasswd.users
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName MySite
  Require valid-user
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from 111.111.111.111
  Satisfy any
```

Im able to bypass but i get a notification

> It appears as though you do not have permission to view information
>   for any of the services you requested...
>
> If you believe this is an error, check the HTTP server authentication
>   requirements for accessing this CGI and check the authorization
>   options in your CGI configuration file.

cgi.cfg

```
authorized_for_system_information=*
authorized_for_configuration_information=*
authorized_for_system_commands=*
authorized_for_all_services=*
authorized_for_all_hosts=*
authorized_for_all_service_commands=*
authorized_for_all_host_commands=*
```

I notice login as ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `use_authentication` set in cgi.cfg, and then also bypass the authentication.

As you have discovered, Nagios doesn't allow you to use the web interface, because it doesn't know which user is logged in.

However, you can use [setenvif](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html) to conditionally set the `REMOTE_USER` environment variable, when connecting from that IP.